# Delete email with specific subject Python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

I have emails coming in that trigger processes but when they have completed I want to delete the email. The subject is the unique id as the sender is always the same.

I have been using a command that deletes all mail but if i get two triggers at the same time one will not get ran.

```py
def deleteEmail(user, pwd, IMAP):

    typ, data = con.search(None, 'ALL')
    for num in data[0].split():
        con.store(num, '+FLAGS', r'(\Deleted)')
    con.expunge()

deleteEmail(user,pwd,con)
```

Comment: How are you accessing the account? What is `con`? When you add some logging to the function, does it appear even though the email is not deleted? Does the `deleteEmail` not run or does it run but the mail is not deleted?

Comment: It runs and works but it deletes all mail. I don't know how to just delete ones with a certain subject. con=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL (imap_url)

Comment: replace "typ, data = con.search(None, 'ALL')" with "typ, data = con.search(None, 'Subject "my subject"')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of doing 
typ, data = con.search(None, 'ALL')
Do this 
typ, data = con.search(None, 'Subject "my subject"')